# Missing Access for Slash Commands

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Heres the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Discord Bot> node .
ready
C:\Users\User\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\User\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\User\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/applications/723863781607997451/guilds/722043668730740788/commands',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

Help is appreciated.
This is my first post on stackoverflow, so if I'm posting something wrong, please tell me!

Comment: I used the wrong guild id

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error is caused because your Discord Bot does not have permission to create commands for that server.

There is two ways to fix this.

## Option 1 - In-App Authorization

You should first navigate to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) then you should click on the bot that you are getting the issue with.

You will then be prompted with this page:

[image: Splash page for the bots Management Panel in Developer Portal]

You should then click on the "OAuth" page, highlighted in red on the above screenshot.

Once you are on this page, you should find the "Default Authorization Link" setting and set it to "In-App Authorization".

[image: Default Authorization Link setting on the OAuth Page of the Developer Portal]

Once that option is selected another option will pop up asking what permissions the bot will ask the user for, you can see the screenshot below.

[image: Scope & Bot Permission settings for Discord Bot]

Select `bot` and `application.commands` then select the permissions that your bot requires.

Then save your changes.
[image: Save your changes]

You will need to re-authorize your bot to the guild before it will work, you do not need to kick it - just click on your bot and click "Add to Server" and re-add it to your guild.

## Option 2 - URL Generation

You should first navigate to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) then you should click on the bot that you are getting the issue with.

Once you are on that page, you should access the OAuth sub-menu titled "URL Generation" as seen below.

[image: URL Generator]

Once you are on this page, you will be presented with a similar output to Option 1, you should configure the scope to be `bot` and `application.commands` and then request permissions as your bot needs.

## Note

You should use both of these with your Discord bot, you should use Option 1 to setup your in-app authorization permissions and then use Option 2 to get a URL for Discord Bot lists, etc.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But the commands list isn't appearing in the / menu. However, the commands still work.

Comment: The custom command cache is for an hour, so just wait up to an hour max and it will show up. If this helped, upvote and mark it as correct so others get help easily if they click on here :)

Comment: I'm using guild-specific commands, not global. Don't guild commands deploy instantly?

Comment: Yeah, apologies "Guild commands update instantly. We recommend you use guild commands for quick testing, and global commands when they're ready for public use." - yeah I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Might be a client issue, try CTRL + R.

Comment: There is no applications.commands.update scope.

Comment: This is dumb, but my issue was I forgot to update which guild I was targeting. Kept adding/removing the bot repeatedly till I realized that.

Comment: Edited post, @Spacehold applications.commands.update scope got merged with applications.commands

Comment: Answer re-edited for changes in Discord Developer Panel and added information about In-App Authorization.